# Print the value of 10 and 11 column from excel using java

Tags: java, excel

I have code to print all the values of excel cells but it's ignoring the blank cells. Is there any way to print the value of blank cell (null) as well?

And also is it possible to print particular 2 specific columns (with blank cells) like 10th and 11th column?

Below is my code. Please suggest what can i change in below code?

```
package excel;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class Excel 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\Users\\gur29175\\Desktop\\1.xlsx"));

            //Create Workbook instance holding reference to .xlsx file
            XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);        
            XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

            //Iterate through each rows one by one
            Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
            while (rowIterator.hasNext())
            {
                Row row = rowIterator.next();
                //For each row, iterate through all the columns
                Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();

                while (cellIterator.hasNext()) 
                {
                    Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
                    //Check the cell type and format accordingly
                            System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue() + "\t");


                }
                System.out.println("");
            }
            file.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Iterate+over+cells%2C+with+control+of+missing+%2F+blank+cells

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Row row = rowIterator.next();
for(int i = 0; i < row.getLastCellNum(); i++) {
    Cell cell = row.getCell(i);
    if(cell != null && cell.getCellType() != Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK) {
       // handle not null values
    }else{
       // handle null values
    }
}
```